# Somehow my bootstrap and jquery files refused to load on an angular project

Tags: javascript, angular, twitter-bootstrap

I have a bootstrap installed via the following command on my angular project

```
 npm install --save bootstrap jquery
  "styles": [
  "../node_modules/bootstrap/scss/bootstrap.scss",
  "styles.scss"
]

    "scripts": [
      "../node_modules/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js",
      "../node_modules/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js"
    ]
```

The problem is that the sass file  never worked until i imported it into the sass file before it worked, meaning my angular.json configuration did not work

```
@import "~bootstrap/scss/bootstrap.scss";// this worked
```

Any help please,  because I have used it on some other project it worked and in others it didn't work. I wanna know what am doing wrong.

Answer (score 0):

Use this approach

```
"styles": [
  "node_modules/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.css"
]
```

Comment: check now bootstrap.css file located in "node_modules/bootstrap/dist/css/"